# How to make a type-bound polymorphic pointer point to an extended type, using a parent type-bound procedure?

Tags: oop, fortran, polymorphism, type-bounds

I am not sure if I wrote the question title right, but I did a MWE to explain me better what I would like to do:

```
module prueba

type    :: basic
  class(basic),pointer  :: myself => null()
  contains
  procedure :: hello => basic_hello
end type
 
type,extends(basic)    :: complicated
  contains
  procedure :: hello => complicated_hello
end type

contains

subroutine basic_hello(a)
class(basic), target  :: a
a%myself=>a       ! <----- XXX
print *, 'I am basic'
end subroutine
 
subroutine complicated_hello(a)
class(complicated), target  :: a
call a%basic%hello()
print *, 'I am complicated'
end subroutine
            
end module

program main
use prueba
type(complicated)    :: a

call a%hello()
! Returns:  
! I am basic
! I am complicated
  
call a%myself%hello()
! Returns:
! I am basic

end program
```

I would like to set the pointer `a%myself` in the basic level, making it polymoprhic, so then I can run any of the extended hello procedure. That is, I would like to also get "I am complicated" legend in the second call (through the pointer). This might no have sense in the MWE, but I think it actually does in my real code. Since this approach is not working, I would like to know why, and what other alternative is possible. Thank you.

Comment: Just a note. If you do the assignment `a%myself=>a` in the main program, it will write what you want. Does that help? The problem is in doing it in the subroutine.

Comment: @VladimirF Yes, that helps. It is quite surprising for me that does not work in the subroutine... not sure why is that. Since I have many extensions, in different modules, it would be better to do `a%myself=>a` only once in the parent subroutine. But yes.. I will do what you suggest if there is not other solution.

Comment: `a%basic` has declared and dynamic type `basic`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main reason is in the

```
call a%basic%hello()
```

that way you are passing a reference which is really `type(basic)` and hence the stored pointer in myself is just a pointer to that part that is of `type(basic)`.

You need to do the assignment

```
a%myself=>a
```

in some context, where the `a` is really of dynamic type `complicated` even if polymorphic `class(basic)`.

That could be in the outer scope, where you have access to the original `type(complicated)` variable or you could, e.g., do

```
call basic_hello(a)
```

instead of the `call a%basic%hello()`.

This passes the `a` that is the argument of `complicated_hello(a)` instead of the `a%basic`.

Comment: Understood. I just tested `call basic_hello(a)` approach and works. Thanks Vladimir. Also, after adding `procedure :: basic_hello` in parent type construct, I have tried `call a%basic_hello()` and also work (avoiding to explicitly make `basic_hello` routine public). Thanks again!